# What is required to run a c# winform program on a computer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a simple c# Winforms program that uses SQL Server and several DLLs. What steps should I do in order to get the program run on another computer?

I.e. should I transfer the exe file + the dlls I used?

Should I also install .net framework 3.5 on the other pc?

I used visual studio 2008 to compile.

Answer (score 7):

1. install .net framework 3.5
2. deploy your app.

You could also create an installer that automatically installs the .net framework for you. Don't forget to deploy the DLL as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a installer using a Setup Project in visual studio instead of copying files. it will take care of most of the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You mention in you question that your application uses also MS SQL. In this case, apart from the .NET Framework, you should also be sure to provide an edition of MS-SQL for the client pcs as well. 
Unless the application is a distributed one, where you would connect to a SQL Server on another server, you will need a copy of SQL Server to be setup on the client pc. You should probably check out either an Express Version or greater edition of MS SQL Server to provide with your application

[SQL Server Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx)

Other than that you should create an installer for your application, either by using the MS Visual Studio Setup Project functionality or any third party installer creation appllication.

[Using Visual Studio Setup Project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the other computer also requires the .net framework in order to run the application.

Comment: If your program needs a DB and it does not assume the DB is installed, you should install that DB and all that is needed to prepare the schema.

Answer (score 0):

obviously you have to install it (Unless its Windows 7 PC, because its already there)

If you use any 3rd party dll's that should be present along with your App

Answer (score 0):

You should install the .net framework. The version of .net framework required depends on what version you used when you created your project. You should also install MS SQL Express on the target machine. After this you can copy the exe and any other dll-s you used or you could make a setup project that makes an installer for you.

Comment: MS SQL Server Express is not necessary unless your application depends on it. If saso means SQL Server Standard or upper editions, Express edition is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

The application made in .Net are are translated to MSIL and tagreted to .net framework, hence you will need .net frame work on the running machine. You can have installer as others have mentioned and that will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a set up project to your solution so that the user can run it and install the application on his computer. If .Net framework 3.5 is not installed on the target computer, the installer will let the user know that it needs to be present to be able to install and run the program. Look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/11/18/how-to-include-net-framework-3-5-sp1-with-your-installer.aspx) for more on this. A set up project will also let you place the output from your application (dll:s and supporting files such as a database) in application folders on the users computer upon installation.